# Decrypt AES128/CBC in Objective-C from PHP

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm new to xCode and Objective-C. I've coded a QR-Scanner, now I need to decrypt the Data which is encryptet with AES128 CBC. I encrypt the plaintext using this snippet in php: http://www.androidsnippets.com/encrypt-decrypt-between-android-and-php

Could you help me pls? Sorry for my bad English, I'm German :D

Comment: **NEVER EVER** trust crypto code from AndroidSnippets. They post the most horrible insecure code, which gets an unlimited amount of attention and votes because of the large number of Android devs that haven't seen a piece of encryption in their entire life. This is just another example of that.

Comment: There's no important data in the code but not everyone must see by the first look what's behind it.

Comment: Good, talk to you again when decryption fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CommonCrypto, See [CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CommonCrypto) and [CCCryptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCCryptor.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CCCryptor)

Here is a snippit to get you started:

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
               error:(NSError **)error
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        dataOut.length = cryptBytes;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"kEncryptionError"
                                         code:ccStatus
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        dataOut = nil;
    }

    return dataOut;
}
```

Also see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for a full implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, how can i call this method?
    NSData *decrypted = [doCipher ....]; ?

Sorry I'm a absolute newbie :/

Comment: You will have to include the the Security framework, #import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>, call it like `[ClassName doCipher ...];` where ClassName is the name of the class it is declared in. Really do consider RNCryptor, it is a compile implementation, what I provided is a snippet for someone versed in Objective-C and crypto in general.

Comment: thanks, it works wonderful :) i forget to convert the qr-data from hex-string to NSData... Thanks! :)